# An odd construction pattern

Tags: c++

I am seeing the following pattern in a lot of some legacy code. I am not familiar with it and cannot fathom why it is there.

In the header file:

```
struct ook
{
  bool func_called; // Not declared as const!
  bool func();
  ook();
};
```

In the source file:

```
ook::ook():
  func_called( func() )
  {} // ← Nothing there whatsoever.

bool ook::func()
{
  // … ← Some stuff without a "return" statement of any kind.
  return true;  // This does mean that func_called is always true.
}
```

Is this some horrible copy-and-paste error from something useful or just oddness?

Now, `func_called` is only called in the constructor and never else in the code. If it was, as kindly pointed out by [Florian Castellane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2918853/florian-castellane) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41764751/232794), it would make sense to have it. If it happened only once, I could imagine this used to be used. However, it happens several dozen times in the code base so I wonder what other use it could have.

Just to be extra clear, this is not my code. I am just trying to understand (and without history, comments, or unit tests) what the logic is writing it was. Maybe it's hopeless?

Comment: Not sure if it has a name or not but it is following the concept that constructors should be empty.  So instead of putting the code to decide what `func_called` should be in the constructor body  and assign that value to a default constructed variable they put it in the function and then call the function in the member initializer which constructs the member directly.  I think the function needs to be static for this though.

Comment: @Nathan Doesn't have to be static.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider So it's legal to call a non-static function  before the class has been fully constructed?

Comment: I've seen _something_ like that, but I think the function in question was `static` and the purpose was to perform more-complicated initialisation of member variables than can normally be done with the `member( value )` format.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes. When virtual functions are involved the ones corresponding to the current stage of construction are called. (This differs from C# where it's perfectly possible to access unconstructed derived members from virtual function calls in base ctors.)

Comment: Also note this is the only way to initialize a `const` variable in a class from reading some data at the time of construction.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider OK.  Just wasn't sure how the lifetime rules applied.  I would assume using a member that has not yet been constructed in the function body would be UB, right?

Comment: If "Some stuff" never returns, then the constructor would never return, which I find highly doubtful. What is "Some stuff"? `abort()`? `terminate()`? `throw`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I guess this means "does not return early", just executes and then falls onto the `return true;`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Some stuff is initialising other class/stucts, doing some networking, setting some initialise state, … It varies a lot. Again, there are several dozen examples of his pattern. This is the overall structure.

Comment: @Sardathrion: Also, your class definition doesn't declare the constructor. :-(

Comment: Interestingly, if you *copy* such an object, the copy would have `func_called == true`, too, but it would of course not have called `func` again.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You know you can edit the post? … Very nice point on the copy!

Comment: I see, you added the ctor declaration in the class definition after I looked last... case closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the rest of the code tests for `true == func_called`, this could be used to ensure the structure is initialized using the constructor.

Comment: Fair point but that never happens in the code. Could be it used to happen and no longer does -- history has been erased due to carelessness ☹

Comment: is this func_called boolean used at all?

Comment: No, it is not. Its sole use seem to be in the constructor. Now, if it was only once I could explain it as stale code but it happens a few dozen times.

Comment: debugging purposes then maybe, if it is not actively used by the program.

Comment: Could be… I am baffled by it.

Comment: I assume that the ctor must be declared in the class definition (the OP is lacking that). In that case *all* objects have been constructed through that ctor, because there is no other way.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Indeed but that is not the case in the code base. Again, this is not my code I am just struggling to see the logic behind it.

Comment: Ah, if the c'tor is not declared in the class definition, then it makes sense that such a struct can be created without the constructor -- hence the flag. If you are refactoring, you definitely want to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're saying is true and nobody uses `ook::func_called`, then your code is equivalent to the following, simpler code:

```
struct ook
{
    ook() { func(); }

    void func() { /* Some stuff */ }
};
```

You should pay great attention to whether copy construction and copy assignment behave as intended.

Comment: `grep` seems to thing it's true…

Comment: @Sardathrion: Does your grep see through macros and line continuations? Maybe better to use clang-query.

Comment: I would love to use clang-query if it was available on RedHat. It is not. As for `grep`, I am pretty sure it catches everything.